# How to change the datatype of a field

Tags: sql, ms-access

I wanted to change one of the fields to currency type during select

```
SELECT AdvertID,NumWords,WeeksRunning,0.5*NumWords*WeeksRunning AS [Cost]
FROM AdvertsTb
```

As you can see, the new field won't be in the format of $XX.00. So which operator must I use to change the type so that it is shown as a currency?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to cast it

```
SELECT AdvertID,NumWords,WeeksRunning,cast(0.5*NumWords*WeeksRunning as money) AS [Cost]
FROM AdvertsTb
```

Comment: There is an error message saying syntax error(missing operator) and it highlighted the "AS" in the cast operator

Comment: My example refers to SqlServer.
If you use access (As described in the below comments for other answers),
try referring to this link:

https://support.office.microsoft.com/en-us/article/Type-Conversion-Functions-8ebb0e94-2d43-4975-bb13-87ac8d1a2202?CorrelationId=dbae06bc-4701-4405-b73a-925e4181c637&ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US

Answer (score 2):

Just convert the `cost` to `varchar` and append `$` symbol.

```
SELECT AdvertID,NumWords,WeeksRunning,
       "$" & CStr(0.5*NumWords*WeeksRunning) AS [Cost]
FROM AdvertsTb
```

Comment: It says unidentified function "convert" in expression

Comment: @Shilon - Use `cast` then. Updated check now. Which database you are using. It looks like you are using `MSSQL`. In `MSSQL` Convert is supported

Comment: Im using microsoft access 2010. The error message says syntax error(Missing operator) in expression and it highlighted AS

Comment: @Shilon - Use `CSTR()` function. Updated check now

Answer (score 0):

You can also try the `CONVERT` method:

```
SELECT 
      AdvertID,
      NumWords,
      WeeksRunning,
      CONVERT(MONEY,0.5*NumWords*WeeksRunning) AS [Cost]
FROM AdvertsTb
```